# Jersey REST services

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey

I'm new to Jersey and RESTful web services. I have a simple service that gets a user ID, searches for associated activities, and returns a `User` POJO with two fields: `userId` and `userName`. `Activity` is also a simple POJO that contains the fields `duration` and `description`, as well as a `User` reference.

I use the annotation `@XmlRootElement` for both classes (`User` and `Activity`).

```
@GET
@Path("/user/{userId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User getActivityUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {
    for (Activity activity : activities) {
        if (activity.getUser().getId().equals(userId)) {
            System.out.println(activity.getUser().toString());
            return activity.getUser();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When i try to run the service, it prints the result in the console but displays an HTTP 500 error my browser. No error is written to the application log.

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500  Internal Server Error</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500  Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Internal Server Error</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.23</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: Look into Server logfiles for more informations

Comment: by any chance activities is null? share log for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using /user again in the Path annotation.
Can you please provide the complete class definition.

@Path("/user/{userId}")

If you have already defined /user as Path annotation for class, you just need to have userID as below for Path annotation of Get message.

```
@GET
@Path("{userId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User getActivityUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) {
  //Code goes here

}
```